# New frame in ASM

Tags: assembly, nasm

Theorically, when I execute a call:

**Stack**

```
Local variables
EBP
RET ADDRESS
Args
...
```

Well, the case is, why when I execute "pop esi" I obtain the RET ADDRESS and not EBP?

```
# NASM
BITS 32

section .text
global _start

_start:
call function
mov eax,0x41414141



function:
# esi get the address of "mov eax,0x41414141"
# but theorically, we should obtain the EBP value, no?
pop esi

# Exit
xor eax,eax
xor ebx,ebx
mov al,0x01
int 0x80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are showing there is "naked", i.e. it doesn't set up a stack frame.

That is something you do manually in assembler, if you need one. Typically it looks something like:

```
function:
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
...
```

And then you must also manually tear it down before returning, typically

```
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
ret n
```

(or I could have used the `leave` instruction)

If you had this, your schematic would have been correct, though it's upside down from how I personally think about it on the Intel platform where the stack grows downward in memory.

Comment: Oh, yes, that obvious fail hehe.